# Oracle driver misbehavior Tomcat 6.0

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, encoding, utf-8

I have a Tomcat 6.0 Application server, with a pretty simple web applcation using an oracle connection. The connection itself is defined in the server.xml file as a JDBCRealm.

The default encoding of the server is latin1. The database encoding is UTF-8. Normally everything works fine, special characters get inserted in the databse as the should and the are retrieved in proper encoding. If I'm not mistaking this is because the Oracle driver resolves any encoding mismatches automatically.

I added the following bit to the catalina.bat file where the AS starts up, to set the encoding that is to be used for Catalina:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

Now I can still save special characters like `ŰÁÉÚŐÖÜÓ`, and they are inserted like this in the database, but if I reload the data on some page the encoding is all messed up. Something like: `ĂĂĂĂĂĂĂĂ`.

So I can still insert, but I can't get data in correct format after I add that line. Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this issue? Or what could maybe cause it? I need this setup because I'm actually trying to recreate an error on another environment.

Comment: Is the problem that your characters look wierd in the browser? Exactly where do you specify `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` in catalina.bat?

Comment: Just before startup. It looks something like %_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS%  -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%JAVA_ENDORSED_DIRS%" etc...

Comment: We had a similar issue and we set the `JAVA_OPTS` with the parameters you use. Could you try to add a line in catalina.bat, somewhere below the row that initializes `JAVA_OPTS`: `set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dfile.encoding=UTF8`

Comment: I'm afraid that the problem is that the UTF-8 setting messes up the otherwise working setup, not that the setting gets ignored, I tried it anyway, got the same result, the problem is that setting this adds some kind if extra layer of character encoding, that totally messes up data transition, though if i play ariund with the encoding of the browser it sometimes get the first reload right as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I kind of figured out what the problem is. I blamed the oracle driver for not doing the conversion right. However the servlet transmitted the values in a wrong format to start with, and displayed them in an even worse fashion. So the actual simple solution was to extend the was xml with a general filter referencing a commonly used encoding fitler, that is also present in the tomcat folder's eaxmple webapps. I added this to web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Set Character Encoding</filter-name>
    <filter-class>filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Set Character Encoding</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And all got well! This will be pretty much the first thing I add to a web.xml from now on. Thanks a lot anyways, Cheers!